# Does declaring an array size explicitly determine pass by value vs reference?

Tags: arrays, go, pass-by-reference

Take this demonstration of an array copy not mutating its parent array:

```
    a1 := [5]string{"English", "Japanese", "Spanish", "French", "Hindi"}
    a2 := a1 
    fmt.Println("a1 = ", a1) //[English Japanese Spanish French Hindi]
    fmt.Println("a2 = ", a2) //[English Japanese Spanish French Hindi]
    a2[1] = "German"
    fmt.Println("now a2 = ", a2) // [English German Spanish French Hindi]
    fmt.Println("and a1 = ", a1) // [English Japanese Spanish French Hindi]
```

No real surprise, a2 is a copy, not a reference. Changing a copy shouldnt change the other one, theyre kept at different addresses.

Now check out what happens  if we dont declare a  size to a1:

```
    a1 := []string{"English", "Japanese", "Spanish", "French", "Hindi"} // <--difference here
    a2 := a1
    fmt.Println("a1 = ", a1) //[English Japanese Spanish French Hindi]
    fmt.Println("a2 = ", a2) //[English Japanese Spanish French Hindi]
    a2[1] = "German"
    fmt.Println("now a2 = ", a2) // [English German Spanish French Hindi]
    fmt.Println("and a1 = ", a1) // [English German Spanish French Hindi]
```

BOTH change when a2 is changed?! So, if you dont declare a size to the array, then assign it to something, suddenly its a reference? Why would a2 := a1 behave completely different depending on how another variable is declared? I am confused lol.

Comment: When you don't declare the size, it's a [slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7), not an array, and it's quite different though a related thing.

Comment: well damn, thats subtle

Comment: See https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6 and the next page.

Comment: Go always passes by value, never by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest reading the Go blog post [Arrays, slices and strings](https://blog.golang.org/slices) - then reading it again - it's packed with lots of other subtle side effects.

It will show what's going on under the hood and how slice-types are represented:

```
sliceHeader{
    Length:        0,
    Capacity:      0,
    ZerothElement: nil, // points to a fixed size array
}
```

and thus how mutation operations may affect more than one slice value.

A final quote:

> Arrays have their place—they are a good representation of a
> transformation matrix for instance—but their most common purpose in Go
> is to hold storage for a slice.